# How can I stop a layer moving down when some layers above show on hover and have a position offset

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just want 50px of whitespace between the orange layer and
`.Container` div with the image and when the layers show on hover the
orange layer should not bump up and down 50px;

Here's the Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/zHARN/58/

Comment: Use `visibility:visible/hidden` instead of `display:block/none` to show and hide levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use absolute positions for the FirstLevel.

http://jsfiddle.net/qqTSv/

CSS:

```
.FirstLevel
{
width: 150px;  
height: 50px;
background-color: green;
position:absolute;    
bottom: 0px;
display: none;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea why there's still a small gap though when they purple layer shows (not a perfect 50px)

Comment: uhmmm, actually, no clue. Don't ask me why, but `top:40px;` for `.ContentBody` solves it. Maybe there's somewhere a padding or a margin of 10px?